# Blender crashes while rendering in GPU but not in CPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I've just started using Blender a few days ago so far I've made a neat little donut.

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QnGt.jpg

I have no problem rendering the scene with CPU but when I choose the GPU Compute setting, Blender crashed by itself.

Here's the user preferences of my Blender 2.78c:
[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQGpS.jpg My graphics card is AMD Radeon (TM) HD 7450A Graphics.

How do I prevent Blender from crashing while rendering with GPU?

btw I'm using Cycles Render

Comment: It's possible that you're running out of GPU memory.  Are you getting any error messages?  Just so you know, depending on what CPU you're using, you might be better off rendering with CPU.  It's possible that you won't see any gain in performance with that card and you might see a loss.

Comment: If the scene you are rendering exceeds the resources of your device then you will see a crash. Usually GPUs have a much smaller amount of vRAM than the RAM you have in your system. If you must render on GPU you have to optimize your scene. There are some complex scene that can only be rendered on CPU.

Comment: The error message says 'Failed loading render kemel, see console for details'.

Comment: we had same issue without having less ram issue etc.
ram hits 18 gb but our ram has 64 gb
gpu ram has 24 gb...
whenever we render via CPU, it works, but when we render on GPU, while we upload textures it crashes... we had tried many driver from Nvidia.. did not work :( we had tried many version of Blender did not help eighter... we also rendered by command line.. still did not work :(